# Is it possible to determine whether the critical values are nowhere dense in the case of a bounded set of stationary points?

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $g:\Bbb R^{d}\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a non-negative, continuously differentiable function satisfying the following two conditions:

1. The set $\{\theta\in\Bbb R^n\mid\|\nabla g(\theta)\|<\eta\}$ is bounded for some $\eta>0$.
2. The gradient of $g$ satisfies the Lipschitz continuity condition, i.e.,
   $$
   \|\nabla g(x)- \nabla g(y)\|\le L\|x-y\|.\quad \forall x, y\in \Bbb R^n
   $$

**Question**. Can we prove that the set $\{g(\theta)\in\Bbb R\mid \exists \theta\in\Bbb R^n\text{ s.t. }\nabla
    g(\theta)=0 \}$ is nowhere dense?

Comment: Note that we cannot directly use Sard's theorem here because we only guarantee first-order continuous differentiability.

Answer (score 7):

The result is true if $d\leq 2$, because the Sard theorem is true for $C^{1,1}$ functions [B]. If $d>2$ there are many counterexamples. For example the following counterexample was constructed in [H]:

> **Theorem.** Given positive integers $n,m$, there is an integer $d>n$ and a compact set $K\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]^n$ such that any continuous function $f:K\to\mathbb{R}$ can be uniformly approximated by functions $g\in C^m(\mathbb{R}^d)$  such that $D^\alpha g=0$ on $K$ for all $|\alpha|\leq m$.

If $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $\phi=1$ on $K$, and $g$ is as in the theorem, then the function $\tilde{g}(x)=g(x)\phi(x)+(1-\phi(x))|x|^2$ satisfies conditions 1. and 2. Since $\tilde{g}=g$ on $K$, it approximates $f$ uniformly on $K$.

If $f:K\to\mathbb{R}$ maps a curve in $K$ onto an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ then any function $\tilde{g}$ that is sufficiently close to $f$ must map $K$ onto an interval and as the theorem says, we can assume that $K$ consists of critical points of $\tilde{g}$.

[B] *Bates, S. M.*, [**Toward a precise smoothness hypothesis in Sard’s theorem**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2159728), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 117, No. 1, 279-283 (1993). [ZBL0767.58003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0767.58003).

[H] *Hajlasz, Piotr*, [**Whitney’s example by way of Assouad’s embedding**](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-03-06913-2), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 131, No. 11, 3463-3467 (2003). [ZBL1061.26010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1061.26010).